# Flutter: Container color overflowing border

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to make a container with rounded borders, color, and an outline, but the background color is overflowing the outline color.

How can I fix this?

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 21,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: 21,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21),
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
        child: Align(
            child: Text(
          "1",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),
        )));
  }
}
```

Result: (most visible on the left side)

[image: Pink overflows white border]

Comment: The problem isn't in this widget. Can you post some other code?

Comment: @tsg that is all the code. I did it in dartpad (screenshot is from the dartpad, no other code there).

Comment: It looks like the background is visible through the border’s pixels that are transparent due to antialiasing.

Comment: @spkersten any fix? Tired different clip behaviors but still happens

Comment: I am putting two circles one on top of the other inside a Stack now, but if there is a more elegant way, I would like to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It... looks like a bug? I think you can report the issue to flutter [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

[image]

If you just want a workaround solution, you can try to move the background color (pink) to the lower level of your widget.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 21,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 21,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21),
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
        child: Align(
          child: Text(
            "1",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13675) in Github regarding this issue.

Here I attached the workaround I found working from @artyomdevyatov's [reply](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13675#issuecomment-636538253).

```
return Container(
  width: 28,
  height: 28,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey, // border color
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2), // border width
    child: Container( // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.orange, // inner circle color
      ),
      child: Container(), // inner content
    ),
  ),
);
```